# Access select using div/span id

Tags: jquery-selectors

In jquery is it possible to access a select element by simply using the div or span id plus the **"select" selector**? I ask because i have a series of auto-generated forms meaning I can't assign an id to the form elements plus the names are weird like "w24", I'd like to access a form element specifically a select using the surrounding span id and "**select"** selector example:

```
$("#hiv_care select").attr("disabled",true);
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work, forcing me to explicitly use the dropdown name.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how it doesn't work? Use http://jsfiddle.com.

Comment: jsfiddle.net is the correct link

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was using the wrong div id. SLaks thanks for the link to jsfiddle.net it exposed my ways and is really helping me with testing out my jquery code.